# Set toggle Button to false with my code behind if method is called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I try to set a toggle button to false if a method was called from my code behind.
Thats my xaml for the button:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="StartScan" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="Start" IsChecked="False" Click="StartScan_Click" Width="80" />
<ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Column="2" Height="22" Width="50" Minimum="0" Maximum="100">
    <ProgressBar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=StartScan}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=StartScan}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```

And what Im doing is call a method if i Click my Toogle Button, thats working but it would be really nice that the Toggle Button would set to `IsChecked="False"` after running my method.

Thats the Method Im calling with the Toogle Button in my code behind:

```
async void StartScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(getAll);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await Task.Run(getGroups);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await Task.Run(GetUsers);

    //not working
    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
    StartScan.IsChecked = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it is very hard to understand what you exepct from this code. You have mashed up two approaches. Try to go either XAML or either Code behind but don't try to fully implement both approaches as you gain nothing and loose readability.

If you want to do it in code behind then get rid of all the styles in XAML and keep the definition simple:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="StartScan" Content="Start" IsChecked="False" Click="StartScan_Click" Width="80" />
<ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Height="22" Width="80" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="False"/>
```

In code behind try to immediately set the progress to indetermined. After that do your tasks and then set the state of the controls to what was previously there. Also, I would suggest you disable the button for the duration of your tasks otherwise the user can click it multiple times.

```
private async void StartScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;
    StartScan.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
    StartScan.IsEnabled = true;
    StartScan.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, I like to use the Toggle Button to start a Method. If the method has done the Tasks the 'pbStatus.IsIndeterminate' should be set to 'false` to stop the Animation. Ive tryed your `pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;` (and false) in StartScan_Click and removed the Xaml Styles but I still cant set them to True or False if I click the Toggle Button. Would it be better to archive all in Xaml or in Codebehind to not mess all my code up?

Comment: This is actually a working example. I have ran this code and when I click the button the button is disabled, the progress is started and it runs for 5 seconds after which the progress stops, the button is enabled and unchecked.

Comment: Could it be because of my progressBar is inside a dataTemplate? If I place the bar outside of the datatemplate it works.